# VB net keydown event trigger tab index

Tags: vb.net

I have set a keydown event to monitor keyboard keypad +- and left and right arrow. Keys 109, 107, 39 and 37. I get the proper key event and keycode  but it also trigger the tab index when I hit right and left arrows. I also set the tabstop to false on all the related buttons and labels that are triggered with the tabindex but no effect. Can I disable tabindex on form entirely? code below of Keydown.

```
    Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    '   If e.KeyCode = Keys.N Then
    '   MsgBox(e.KeyCode)

    Select Case e.KeyCode

        Case 109                        '// (-) Key

            If intSequenceNumber = 0 Then
            '//Do nothing
        Else
            intSequenceNumber = intSequenceNumber - 1
            Label_ChaseNumber.Text = intSequenceNumber + 1

            LoadStepPattern()

        End If


        Case 107                        '// (+) Key

            If intSequenceNumber < 99 Then

            intSequenceNumber = intSequenceNumber + 1
            Label_ChaseNumber.Text = intSequenceNumber + 1

            LoadStepPattern()

        End If


        Case 39                       '// (Right Arrow) Key

            If intStepNumber < 99 Then

                ResetAllBorders()

                intStepNumber = intStepNumber + 1
                PicPixel(intStepNumber).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
            End If


        Case 37                       '// (Right Arrow) Key

            If intStepNumber = 0 Then
                'Do Noting

            Else

                ResetAllBorders()

                intStepNumber = intStepNumber - 1
                PicPixel(intStepNumber).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
            End If

    End Select


End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Have you tried `e.Handled = True` within the arrow blocks?

Comment: Do you mean the cursor moves to the next field when left/right is pressed? I tried a little test with two textboxes, but the left and right arrow keys do not trigger a tab. Have you set the KeyPreview property to True?

Comment: Keypriew = true, Not curser it sets focus to each item in the form.

Comment: Try adding `e.Handled = True` at the end of each case block

Comment: e.handled=true did solve the tab issue but when I start application and press one of the keys it sets focus to one of my combobox in the form not associated with the keydown sub. Any thoughts?